# Independence of sum of random variables with respect to another sum of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If X_1 is independent of Y_1 and X_2 is independent of Y_2, ... , X_n is independent of Y_n, then it holds true that X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n is independent of Y_1 + Y_2 + ... + Y_n. Right? Or is there a counter example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true.  Consider two iid random variables $Z_1, Z_2$ with $\mathbb{P}(Z_1 = 1) = \mathbb{P}(Z_2 = -1) = \frac 12$.  Let $X_1 = Z_1$, $X_2 = Z_2$, and $Y_1 = Y_2 = Z_1 Z_2$.  Then $X_1 \perp Y_1$, $X_2 \perp Y_2$, but $X_1 + X_2 = 0$ iff $Y_1 + Y_2 = -2$, so $X_1 + X_2$ is not independent of $Y_1 + Y_2$.

Comment: And what if the X_i are independent to each other and the Y_i are also independent to each other? Does my statement hold true in that case?

Comment: @Leo Still no.  In this same example, you could take $Y_2 = 0$ (since constants are always independent of everything) and you would still have $\mathbb{P}(Y_1=1,X_1+X_2 = 2) = \frac 14 \ne \mathbb{P}(Y_1 = 1) \mathbb{P}(X_1+X_2 = 2)$, so $Y_1 +Y_2=Y_1$ is still not independent of $X_1+X_2$.  You can create more examples like this by finding random variables that are pairwise independent but not jointly independent.